# p-value for complete spatial randomness tests

Tags: hypothesis-testing, spatial, point-process

I am using the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test to study the homogeneity of a point pattern in 3D using the distance transform to a structure as a covariate.

I am using the [spatstat book](https://www.crcpress.com/Spatial-Point-Patterns-Methodology-and-Applications-with-R/Baddeley-Rubak-Turner/p/book/9781482210200), where it is explained (Section 10.5) that the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test statistic ($D$) can be calculated as the maximum vertical separation between the cumulative distribution function of the spatial covariate evaluated at the data points ($F_0(z)$) and at all locations ($\hat{F}(z)$). It is:

$D = \max\limits_z|\hat{F}(z)-F_0(z)|$

However, I do not understand how to obtain the value $D$ for my null hypothesis (that the points are homogeneously distributed) so that I can compare them and know whether I can reject the null hypothesis.

If there is also a formula to calculate the critical p-value would be excellent, since I read how to calculate it when you compare your data with a defined distribution like Poisson, but in this case I understand that I should use $\hat{F}(z)$ as the distribution to compare.

Furthermore, I could only use this test in spatstat for 2D data, but not for 3D. If will also appreciate any hint about how to do it.

EDIT: 
Following the example in the spatstat book, what I am doing is:

```
elev <- bei.extra$elev
cdf.test(bei,elev)
```

Which produces this result:

```
Spatial Kolmogorov-Smirnov test of CSR in two dimensions

data:  covariate ‘elev’ evaluated at points of ‘bei’ 
     and transformed to uniform distribution under CSR
D = 0.10634, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

As far as I understand, $D$ is calculated with the formula above, however that says nothing about the rejection of the null hypothesis. Now I would like to know how the p-value can be calculated.

As I want to do this test in 3D data, I apply the distance transform in 3D to the structure of interest (covariate), and I compare its result evaluated at all locations $\hat{F}(z)$ and at the observed points ($F_0(z)$). Then, I can compare the distributions as in this figure:

[image]

At this point I know how to calculate $D$, but again, that does not tell if the null hypothesis can be rejected. In this figure it looks obvious that the the points are not homogeneously distributed, but I would like to calculate with which p-value I can reject the null hypothesis.

**EDIT 2: Two-Sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test.**
Up to now I have been using the two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test as Ege Rubak mentioned in his answer. I was using the MATLAB function kstest2 that calculates the p-value based on the number of samples in $x$ (`length(x)`) and $y$ (`length(y)`), where $x$ is a vector with the data points and $y$ the covariate values at the grid points.

The problem is that the size of $y$ corresponds to the number of pixels in the image and are not ‘real’ samples. This means that if my image has a small pixel size or I use a smaller grid (independently of the real volume of the sample) it will be easier to reject the null hypothesis. As far as I understand (please correct me if I am wrong) the test should only consider the size of $x$, since it contains the real samples, and not `length(y)`.

Now I was checking the R code that Ege Rubak proposed to understand what it is actually doing, and I found that the `ks.test` function calls the function `psmirnov2x` in C code (which I could not found). The inputs of this function are $D$ (maximum distance between CDFs), `length(x)` and `length(y)`, so I understand that in this function the p-value is also based on the lengths of both vectors. Am I wrong thinking that this is not the correct approach? Or should I find a different way of doing this test?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide an example of what you have done so far. If you can't share your real data use some of the built-in datasets of `spatstat` or generate them artificially.

Comment: Thank you for the interest. I have included more details, I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in `spatstat` calls `ks.test()` which is a default R function
(in `stats` package), so the actual calculation of the p-value under the
null hypothesis is done there. In the `spatstat` code a few tricks are
done (e.g. transformation to uniform distribution using the inverse
CDF), so it might not be easy to follow that code. I see two different
options:

1. Quick and dirty with two sample KS test.
2. Transform to uniform distribution and use one sample KS test.

### Option 1

I think you can simply calculate the two sample KS test and get what you
want. Simply put the covariate values at the data points in a vector `x`
and the covariate values at the grid points in a vector `y` and then do
`ks.test(x,y)`. In principle the more grid points you can afford the
better. As you add more grid points I expect the p-value converges to
the optimal you can get from a two sample KS test. It may however still
be different (probably conservative) than what the p-value a one sample
KS test would give. Following the example from the book:

```r
require(spatstat, quietly = TRUE)
#> 
#> spatstat 1.49-0.011       (nickname: 'Instinctively Correct') 
#> For an introduction to spatstat, type 'beginner'
# Covariate image
elev <- bei.extra$elev
# Data values:
x <- elev[bei]
# Grid values (simply extracted from image):
y <- as.matrix(elev)
# Test
test <- ks.test(x,y)
#> Warning in ks.test(x, y): p-value will be approximate in the presence of
#> ties
test
#> 
#>  Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
#> 
#> data:  x and y
#> D = 0.10568, p-value < 2.2e-16
#> alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

The issue with tied values is solved in `spatstat` by jittering values,
but I will leave that to you.

### Option 2

If you want to use a one sample test you can use that under the null
hypothesis *Z*(*x*<sub>*i*</sub>) (covariate values at data points) has
theoretical CDF *F*<sub>*Z*</sub> (true spatial CDF of covariate *Z*)
and then *F*<sup>−1</sup>(*Z*(*x*<sub>*i*</sub>)) is uniformly
distributed, so you can make this transformation and do
`ks.test(x, "punif")`, with the transformed values in `x`. This is
effectively what is happening in `spatstat`. I don't expect you will get
a huge difference from the two sample test, but it might depend on the
number of data points you have.

Comment: Please see "EDIT 2: Two-Sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test" in my question. Thank you again.

Comment: Hi @alvgom I have now edited the question. Does that help?

Comment: Yes, it helped a lot. I tried both options and you were right, the critical p-value is almost the same when there are no ties. In the presence of ties I found the first option is more robust, which makes sense considering the effect of ties when calculating the inverse CDF. Thank you for your help.